# What can be done to add the Lambdalabs repository to Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: repository

This `Err: 6` has stopped my attempt to install "Lambda Stack". What is the work around to install lambdalabs.com repository?

```
Err:6 . . . lambdalabs.com/ubuntu disco Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 52.218.209.43 80]
. . .        
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository '. . .  disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: the obvious one to me: change the release to a supported release.

Comment: Rinzwind,, thanks. Do you know the process to petition for a supported release? Seems as if that would be a long process and I'm interested in making this project work now. Specifically, I am trying to add Lambda Stack to my computer and I need this repository.

Comment: see the answer. the 2nd part is what I meant with my 1st comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [their website](https://lambdalabs.com/lambda-stack-deep-learning-software) they have a universal installation method that is supported for LTS releaes:

```
LAMBDA_REPO=$(mktemp) && \
wget -O${LAMBDA_REPO} https://lambdalabs.com/static/misc/lambda-stack-repo.deb && \
sudo dpkg -i ${LAMBDA_REPO} && rm -f ${LAMBDA_REPO} && \
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y lambda-stack-cuda
```

For 19.04 you would get the 18.04 version and this will circumvent your problem with the PPA.

Regarding the PPA: if a release is not supported the general idea is to change the version to install.  Example:

[image]

And then you can use the regular

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y lambda-stack-cuda
```

Comment: Thanks again. By version are you referring to Ubuntu. I just updated to 19.04. Is it possible to boot into 18.04 after reboot and then boot back to 19.04?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this answer in the future - I'm running Pop 20.10 and had the exact same issue with the repo. I changed the version from "groovy" (20.10) to "focal" (20.04), since Lambda Stack only supports LTS versions.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lambda-repository.list` looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.lambdalabs.com/ubuntu focal main
# deb-src http://archive.lambdalabs.com/ubuntu groovy main
```

Then, simply installing lambda-stack-cuda works.

Comment: This only works for 20.04 and 20.10 - the original question on this is 19.04 whwich is End of Life.

Comment: My mistake - was the only question surrounding this I could find, so was just trying to add a more modern answer.